# How do I bind an Rx Bool to selectedSegmentIndex of a SegmentedController?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, segmentedcontrol

I have an `rx` `observable` returning a `Bool` that I need to bind to a `SegmentedControl`'s `selectedSegmentIndex`. The `function` looks like this:

```
func getLockPower() -> Observable<Bool> {
    do {
        return try doorModeService.getDoorLockPower().map { $0.rawValue == 1 }.asObservable()
    } catch {
        return .error(error)
    }
}
```

And I have tried `binding` it to my `SegementedControl` like this:

```
lockViewModel.getLockPower()
             .bind(to: lockInstalledSegmentController.rx.selectedSegmentIndex)
             .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But I get the `error`:

> > No exact matches in call to instance method 'bind'

I don't think I get the syntax, and I haven't been able to find any source on how it should look like. Any suggestions?

Comment: `selectedSegmentIndex` is a `ControlProperty<Int>`, it doesn't make sense to bind a `Observable<Bool>` to it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, just figured it out hehe. Changed it to an Int instead and it worked. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I worked it out. The index obviously need an `Int`, so instead of mapping to `Bool` I mapped to an `Int` and it worked.